# SYN Cookies on a LAN server - Ok / advisable to disable?

Tags: linux, tcp, sysctl

We are looking at tuning our linux tcp stack on one of our lan boxes.

We were wondering if it is ok / advisable to disable SYN cookies on a server that doesnt have any sort of external (eg: "internet") access.

Is it ok to disable syn cookies on a LAN only server via `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies`?

Answer (score 4):

SYN cookies are disabled by default.  That should be a reasonable indication of what you should be doing, absent specific knowledge to the contrary.  More specifically, [`tcp`(7) says](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html):

> The syncookies feature attempts to protect a
>                socket from a SYN flood attack.  This should be used as a last resort,
>                if at all.  This is a violation of the TCP protocol, and conflicts with
>                other areas of TCP such as TCP extensions.  It can cause problems for
>                clients and relays.  It is not recommended as a tuning mechanism for
>                heavily loaded servers to help with overloaded or misconfigured
>                conditions.

Comment: many linux distributions, including centos which we are using, default to net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1 via /etc/sysctl.conf. default as in, on fresh install net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1 exists in /etc/sysctl.conf.

Comment: So your distro overrides the default.  That doesn't change the fact that it *is* the default in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Syncookies are enabled by default to prevent system crash in case of excessive syn requests, if you are expecting a very high rate of connections for e.g. test machine then you can disable it no problem via sysctl

Comment: @AndrewSmith: You can't crash a Linux server with a SYN flood.  You can only starve the server from being able to accept legitimate TCP connection requests.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are doing it the right way.

If you have some need or some problems (then say it :) then tweak the tcp stack otherwise leave it as it is.
Why would you disable syncookies what is the benefit you are expecting?